# Desplazar scroll hacia un div dentro de otro div que tienen overflow con Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo este `div`:

```html
<div style="overflow:scroll;height:90vh">
<div style="height:100px;" id-div="div1">hola soy div 1</div>
<div style="height:100px;" id-div="div2">hola soy div 2</div>
<div style="height:100px;" id-div="div3">hola soy div 3</div>
<div style="height:100px;" id-div="div4">hola soy div 4</div>
<div style="height:100px;" id-div="div5">hola soy div 5</div>
</div>
```

lo que deseo es que al dar click en

```
<button data-scroll="div3">Ir al div 3</button>
```

mi contenedor me aparezca con el scroll en `div3`.

NOTA IMPORTANTE:

- Esto lo deseo porque tengo enlaces con 3 contenidos, y esos contenidos estan montados en un modal, entonces cuando abro contenido 1 me tiene que desplazar hacia contenido 1.
- los contenidos se encuentran en un modal hide que contienen un `div` con `overflow`.

Answer (score 2):

Podrías hacer múltiples query selector a los elementos que necesitas, por ejemplo en primer lugar obtienes el valor del aributo `data-scroll` y con esto puedes hacer otra query donde busques un elemento cuyo attributo `id-div` sea igual al valor que se obtuvo anteriormente, si el elemento existe ejecutas el método `scrollIntoView` que permite que el elemento se haga visible dentro de una caja de scroll, puedes añadir más configuraciones a este dependiendo de como esperas que se comporte el movimiento del scroll

```js
function scrollToElement(event) {
  const scrollTarget = event.target.getAttribute('data-scroll');
  const scrollElement = document.querySelector(`[id-div="${scrollTarget}"]`);

  scrollElement.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
```

```html
<div style="overflow: scroll; height: 200px">
  <div style="height: 100px" id-div="div1">hola soy div 1</div>
  <div style="height: 100px" id-div="div2">hola soy div 2</div>
  <div style="height: 100px" id-div="div3">hola soy div 3</div>
  <div style="height: 100px" id-div="div4">hola soy div 4</div>
  <div style="height: 100px" id-div="div5">hola soy div 5</div>
</div>

<button data-scroll="div3" onclick="scrollToElement(event)">Ir al div 3</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para lograr un scroll suave a un destino interno (en la misma página), solo basta con un estilo en **CSS**, un `href` y un `id` en el **HTML5**.

El CSS debe ser así:

```
html {
 scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

El enlace debe contener un **#** con el destino:

```
<a href="#div-1">
 <button>Ir al div 1</button>
</a>
```

El destino debe tener una `id` igual a su enlace **#**:

```
<div style="height:100px;" id-div="div1">hola soy div 1</div>
```

Lo que hace `scroll-behavior: smooth;` en **html**, es un scroll suave de un enlace a un destino interno: `id`.